# How to print a date ignoring the timezone offset?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I have set my OS timezone to UTC-11 (Samoa). When I do:

```js
const date = new Date("1990-01-01"); // in my real scenario, the user will set a random date using a datepicker

const randomLocale = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "en" : "es";

console.log(date.toLocaleDateString(randomLocale, {
  year: "numeric",
  month: "long",
  day: "numeric",
}));
```

as expected, I am getting one day off:

> "December 31, 2018"

In order to solve it, I have decided to use moment.js, like this:

```js
console.log(moment(date).utc().format())
```

Which results in:

> "2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"

Nice! But... how can I do to get the output string in the same format as when using toLocaleDateString()?

Comment: Can you use the [docs](https://momentjs.com/) from moment to format date strings?

Answer (score 0):

Both

`console.log(moment(date).utc().format("ll"))`

and

`console.log(moment(date).utc().format("LL"))`

work correctly!